# Trend calculation using snowflake sql

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, linear-regression, trend

I have a request to get the trend for Nov-22 and Dec-22 based on the below data for x 9 & 10. Is it possible to use any of the sql linear regression function to accomplish this request ?

below is a sample, I am trying to get the trend for the unknown (Nov & Dec)

```
with
data_table(month, x, y) as
(
    select * from values
      ('Mar-22',1 ,7894),
      ('Apr-22',2 ,7964),
      ('May-22',3 ,8016),
      ('Jun-22', 4, 8005),
      ('Jul-22', 5, 8063),
      ('Aug-22', 6, 8101),
      ('Sep-22', 7, 8101),
      ('Oct-22', 8, 8204)
)
SELECT * FROM data_table;
```

I would like the output to be like:

| Month | Order | Amount | Trend |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mar-22 | 1 | 7894 | 7937.622222 |
| Apr-22 | 2 | 7964 | 7983.272222 |
| May-22 | 3 | 8016 | 8028.922222 |
| Jun-22 | 4 | 8005 | 8074.572222 |
| Jul-22 | 5 | 8063 | 8120.222222 |
| Aug-22 | 6 | 8101 | 8165.872222 |
| Sep-22 | 7 | 8101 | 8211.522222 |
| Oct-22 | 8 | 8204 | 8257.172222 |
| Nov-22 | 9 | 8305 | 8302.822222 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with data_table(month, x, y) as
(
    select * from values
      ('Mar-22',1 ,7894),
      ('Apr-22',2 ,7964),
      ('May-22',3 ,8016),
      ('Jun-22',4, 8005),
      ('Jul-22',5, 8063),
      ('Aug-22',6, 8101),
      ('Sep-22',7 , 8101),
      ('Oct-22',8 , 8204)
)
select
    REGR_SLOPE(y, x) as rs
    ,REGR_INTERCEPT(y,x) as ri
from data_table;
```

works as expected. And thus the extra values can be found:

```
with data_table(month, x, y) as
(
    select * from values
      ('Mar-22',1 ,7894),
      ('Apr-22',2 ,7964),
      ('May-22',3 ,8016),
      ('Jun-22',4, 8005),
      ('Jul-22',5, 8063),
      ('Aug-22',6, 8101),
      ('Sep-22',7 , 8101),
      ('Oct-22',8 , 8204)
)
select 
    nx,
    round(ri + (nx*rs),1) as ny
from values (9),(10) as n(nx)
cross join (    
    select
        REGR_SLOPE(y, x) as rs
        ,REGR_INTERCEPT(y,x) as ri
    from data_table
)
```

| NX | NY |
| --- | --- |
| 9 | 8213.2 |
| 10 | 8250.9 |

with estimated values:

```
with data_table(month, x, y) as
(
    select * from values
      ('Mar-22',1 ,7894),
      ('Apr-22',2 ,7964),
      ('May-22',3 ,8016),
      ('Jun-22',4, 8005),
      ('Jul-22',5, 8063),
      ('Aug-22',6, 8101),
      ('Sep-22',7 , 8101),
      ('Oct-22',8 , 8204)
), output as (
    select * from data_table
    union all 
    select * from values
     ('Nov-22',9 ,null),
     ('Dec-22',10 ,null)
)
select 
    n.*,
    round(ri + (n.x*rs),1) as ny
from output as n
cross join (    
    select
        REGR_SLOPE(y, x) as rs
        ,REGR_INTERCEPT(y,x) as ri
    from data_table
)
order by n.x
```

| MONTH | X | Y | NY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mar-22 | 1 | 7894 | 7911.5 |
| Apr-22 | 2 | 7964 | 7949.2 |
| May-22 | 3 | 8016 | 7986.9 |
| Jun-22 | 4 | 8005 | 8024.6 |
| Jul-22 | 5 | 8063 | 8062.4 |
| Aug-22 | 6 | 8101 | 8100.1 |
| Sep-22 | 7 | 8101 | 8137.8 |
| Oct-22 | 8 | 8204 | 8175.5 |
| Nov-22 | 9 |  | 8213.2 |
| Dec-22 | 10 |  | 8250.9 |

Comment: Thank you so much, I am going to take a look your code . This is helpful. However, we currently use TREND function in excel, where we get the trend for every month. I should have told this in my first post. Is this equitant of the Trend function or what would be the better approach to get the trend ?

Comment: Nod, this is why it is usual to post your expected output, with your input and question.

Comment: |Month|Order|Amount|Trend|
|:----|:----|:----|:----|
|Mar-22|1|7894|7937.622222|
|Apr-22|2|7964|7983.272222|
|May-22|3|8016|8028.922222|
|Jun-22|4|8005|8074.572222|
|Jul-22|5|8063|8120.222222|
|Aug-22|6|8101|8165.872222|
|Sep-22|7|8101|8211.522222|
|Oct-22|8|8204|8257.172222|
|Nov-22|9|8305|8302.822222|

Comment: Sorry about that, is there any workaround ? Trend from excel uses =TREND($C$3:$C$11,$B$3:$B$11,B3). PS: I am not getting the desired table format, but this is the trend I was expecting

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was seeing your code, and the value of slope for all rows is same, is that correct ?

Comment: That is how a linear regression works, you build the LR over "some data" then sample at the locations you wish, be those inside the data (but in gaps) or assume the linear model holds outside the sample window, in a forward or backwards sense.

Comment: I am now getting the whole code and the logic, thank you for your response. –

Answer (score 0):

You inspired me to go and implement linear regression in SQL Server. This could be modified for MySQL/Oracle/Whatever without too much trouble. It's the mathematically best way of determining the trend over the hour for each entity_id and it will select out only the ones with a positive trend.

It implements the formula for calculating B1hat listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis#Linear_regression

```
create table #temp
(
    entity_id int,
    value int,
    [date] datetime
)

insert into #temp (entity_id, value, [date])
values
(1,10,'20140102 07:00:00 AM'),
(1,20,'20140102 07:15:00 AM'),
(1,30,'20140102 07:30:00 AM'),
(2,50,'20140102 07:00:00 AM'),
(2,20,'20140102 07:47:00 AM'),
(3,40,'20140102 07:00:00 AM'),
(3,40,'20140102 07:52:00 AM')

select entity_id, 1.0*sum((x-xbar)*(y-ybar))/sum((x-xbar)*(x-xbar)) as Beta
from
(
    select entity_id,
        avg(value) over(partition by entity_id) as ybar,
        value as y,
        avg(datediff(second,'20140102 07:00:00 AM',[date])) over(partition by entity_id) as xbar,
        datediff(second,'20140102 07:00:00 AM',[date]) as x
    from #temp
    where [date]>='20140102 07:00:00 AM' and [date]<'20140102 08:00:00 AM'
) as Calcs
group by entity_id
having 1.0*sum((x-xbar)*(y-ybar))/sum((x-xbar)*(x-xbar))>0
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I am going to take a look your code . This is helpful. However, we currently use TREND function in excel, where we get the trend for every month. I should have told this in my first post. Is this equitant of the Trend function or what would be the better approach to get the trend ? –

Comment: I cannot follow the code, is this something you can tweak it for my request please ? I have data monthly, and I am trying to get the trend. for example, data can stop in Oct-22, but I need the trend till Dec-22